# 18.04: How to disable swap memory? fstab shows no swap; where does it load from, and how to disable it?

Tags: ram, swap

## cat /etc/fstab

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
#LABEL=UEFI     /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0 0
```

## df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           747M  876K  747M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       9.6G  1.4G  8.2G  15% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop1       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/118
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           747M     0  747M   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop3       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/121
```

## lsblk

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 91.3M  1 loop /snap/core/8592
loop1     7:1    0 91.2M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-sdk/118
loop2     7:2    0 91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
loop3     7:3    0   92M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-sdk/121
sda       8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  9.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

## free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.3G        215M        6.4G        888K        716M        6.9G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

I don't find anything like **swap** in the **fstab** . Then from where it is loading !!
and how to disable it?????

Comment: You have no swap, so there is nothing to disable!

Comment: Your swap is 0 bytes total. :~)

Comment: The ``free`` command shows the amount of "free and used physical and swap memory in the system" according to the man page. It is going to show the amount of swap memory no matter what. It is simply showing you that you have no Swap memory on your system.

Comment: You NEED a swap partition or /swapfile. Why did/are you running without one? Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`,

Answer (score 1):

Swap is not in RAM (unless you use [ZRAM](https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-part2-zram/) which allows you to use CPU power if you are short on both RAM and disk space for swapping); it's in a swap file or swap partition.  Swap is explained in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq and  https://opensource.com/article/18/9/swap-space-linux-systems and in greater detail at https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html .

It's highly recommended to have a swap partition if you have added Hibernation to your system or use ZFS; otherwise, a swap file is much easier to manage and, ever since kernel 4.13 (i.e., Ubuntu 17.10), is just as fast as a swap partition.  Not having a swap file can lead to disk thrashing and performance problems.